# Play framework: JsonNode streaming/chunking

Tags: java, json, playframework, jackson, backend

I have a large map that I want to return to the frontend. Originally I was converting the map to a jackson json node and returning the map back to the user with the return ok() method that play provides.

Original code:

```
public Result returnResponse() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> returnMap = populateMapWithData();
    JsonNode response = mapper.valueToTree(returnMap);
    return ok(response);
}
```

Since the map can be really large, I am running into memory issues.

On looking at the play framework documentation, there are two ways to return large data to the frontend. If the size is known I can stream the data back to the user. If the size is not known, I can provide the data in chunks.

Play Framework documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaStream

For streaming:

```
public Result index() {
  java.io.File file = new java.io.File("/tmp/fileToServe.pdf");
  java.nio.file.Path path = file.toPath();
  Source<ByteString, ?> source = FileIO.fromPath(path);

  Optional<Long> contentLength = null;
  try {
    contentLength = Optional.of(Files.size(path));
  } catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
  }

  return new Result(
      new ResponseHeader(200, Collections.emptyMap()),
      new HttpEntity.Streamed(source, contentLength, Optional.of("text/plain")));
}
```

For chunking:

```
public Result index() {
  // Prepare a chunked text stream
  Source<ByteString, ?> source =
      Source.<ByteString>actorRef(256, OverflowStrategy.dropNew())
          .mapMaterializedValue(
              sourceActor -> {
                sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString("kiki"), null);
                sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString("foo"), null);
                sourceActor.tell(ByteString.fromString("bar"), null);
                sourceActor.tell(new Status.Success(NotUsed.getInstance()), null);
                return NotUsed.getInstance();
              });
  // Serves this stream with 200 OK
  return ok().chunked(source);
}
```

My questions are:

1. How do I get the same result for a Jackson json node?
2. Is there another way to approach large dataset issues with the play framework?|
3. Do we have other play framework documentation for JSON streaming?

Comment: Does it work if you save the JSON to a file with [`writeValue()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue(java.io.File,%20java.lang.Object)), or do you still get memory issues?

Comment: I have not tried that, not sure if that is supposed to work that way though.

Comment: What I mean is, my datasource is a db, I do not want the overhead of reading data from db, writing to a file, and then reading the data from that file.

Answer (score 0):

By my opinion you must implement stream code design f.e.:

- function `populateMapWithData()` must return stream of data, one returned element - one json node (or array of nodes, i think werry little nodes can made you response very slow)
- function `populateMapWithData()` must get data from database by piece (when stream will try get next part of data), for save you memory
- for result you must use `Chunked responses` because you don't know real size of content, more details in [PlayFramwork Doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaStream#Chunked-responses) same link that in you question
- in client side you can read every chunk or chunks array, because this approved of json specification

I lets tried make different design sample:

```java
Results.ok().chunked( //chunked result
   Source.fromPublisher(s -> // publisher read all data by chunks
      mapper.valueToTree(populateEntryWithData(s))));

Object populateEntryWithData(Subscriber<? super T> s) {
   //todo implement page reading for data
   //todo or you can try use reactive driver for database
}
```

**ATTENTION**
In play framework for working with json usually will be better use `play.libs.Json` or inject `ObjectMapper` or inject `ObjectMapperBuilder`.
If you need add more configuration for object mapper you can call `mapper.copy()`, else you can corrupt another internal mapping function in service